# rsync to sync only current day files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rsync

I want to copy only current days files from remote server. is it possible through rsync?? I am trying below command but it is syncing all the files.

/usr/bin/rsync -avurzl #####@$$$$$$$$$ :/opt/test/logs/  /var/logs/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `find` to find files that have changed in the past N days, and combine it with `rsync` like so:

```
find . find -mtime +1 -print0 | xargs -J % -0 rsync -aP % user@host:some/dir/
```

Comment: thanks but i need to pull  data from remote server through rsync but the command you have mentioned is to push the data from remote server.

Comment: thanks but i need to pull  data from remote server through rsync but the command you have mentioned is to push the data from remote server.